# In App Billing managed and unmanaged state for product

Tags: android, in-app-purchase

I am very new to android.. I am working on In App billing.. My question is what is the main purpose of Managed and Unmanaged state while adding the In App product..

Can any one tell  me what is the use of managed state and what is the use of unmanaged state..

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The main difference between managed and un-managed is that a managed purchase can only be bought once and is tied to the Google account that purchases it.

Un-managed purchases can be bought multiple times and are intended for consumable items.

For more information, please see the [Choosing a Purchase Type](http://developer.android.com/guide/market/billing/billing_admin.html#billing-purchase-type) section of the Google in-app billing documentation.

Comment: (why couldn't they just call them "consumable" is beyond me...)

Answer (score 7):

As of Version 3 of Google's IAP Billing API this has changed. Both consumable (multiple purchase) and non-consumable items are "managed". Tf you want to use Version 3 of their API, all purchases must be created as "managed". You can then decide if the item should be consumed later.

Here's a link to their docs: http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/api.html#consumetypes

Answer (score 0):

**UnManaged** could be something like "Buy 50 points"

The 50 points would then be added to your account and you would store this on your accounts server, therefore the Android Market no longer needs to know that you purchased this product i.e. it will not remember your purchase and you can purchase it multiple times.

**Managed** could be "Buy this song"

In this scenario you do not have a server to record that they bought the song and so every time they reinstall you can query the market to see they bought the song and it will not let you download it more than once.

**Managed** is aimed at **one time downloads** then you 'own that object'.

**UnManaged** is for **multiple downloads** of the same thing to 'top something up'.

Answer (score -1):

**UnManaged** could be something like "Buy 50 points"

The 50 points would then be added to your account and you would store this on your accounts server, therefore the Android Market no longer needs to know that you purchased this product i.e. it will not remember your purchase and you can purchase it multiple times.

**Managed** could be "Buy this song"

In this scenario you do not have a server to record that they bought the song and so every time they reinstall you can query the market to see they bought the song and it will not let you download it more than once.

**Managed** is aimed at one time downloads then you 'own that object'.

**UnManaged** is for multiple downloads of the same thing to 'top something up'.

Least thats my understanding.

Version 3 has the concept of 'consumables' and it works inline with the above. All products are **managed** but you can 'consume' a product.

i.e. "Buy 50 points" will give the user fifty managed points, the user will not be allowed to purchase that item again until you consume that product.

Therefore you can make **unmanaged** products by consuming instantly, or **managed** products by consuming when the user has "used" that product (i.e. never call consume for buying a song).

Comment: All you did was copy and paste this guy's answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9391123/difference-between-managed-and-unmanaged-in-app-product-android

At least try to re-word it or add something new to the answer.