# What is google play in app product type difference in Managed, Unmanaged and Subscriptions?

Tags: android, google-play

I am confused between managed, unmanaged and Subscriptions.
please any one help to denunciate them.

Answer (score 0):

This questions has been answered before:

[Difference between managed and unmanaged in-app product android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9391123/difference-between-managed-and-unmanaged-in-app-product-android)

[In App Billing managed and unmanaged state for product](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7597818/in-app-billing-managed-and-unmanaged-state-for-product)

You can find more information for subscription type here http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/api.html#producttype