# How to handle in app-purchases in multiples

Tags: android, in-app-purchase

I'm working on the in-app purchases for an android game and I'm finding the description of managed content a bit ambiguous. Let's say the user does "Purchase five bombs." Should the item be five bombs or should bombs be tracked as a single item that is "bought" five at a time. I know the managed items keep track of their count. Does this mean if I use buy five and it's a single item the store will only tell me I own one?

In general I'm just hoping to get a better description of how to handle purchasing of multiples of an item.

Comment: The item should be "5 bombs" (and not 5 x bomb), i've asked a similar question before:


 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27060427/android-in-app-billing-multiple-purchases-of-the-same-item

Comment: @Rami so does that mean it needs to be unmanaged? Is there a way to do this with managed items?

Comment: All products are managed now.  The user can buy the product again after your app has indicated that it's been consumed.

Comment: Take a look at :http://stackoverflow.com/a/14619835/4224337 . The problem is that: if you declare *bomb* as item, you cant send a resquest to get *N x bomb* but you can send *N* times a request for 1 bomb (this is not recommended because the user must confirm google dialog for each purchase, N times). As a solution, i suggest you to create pkg of *bomb* (e.g 3_bombs, 5_bombs, 20_bombs...)

Comment: @Rami right, but does that mean I need to track how many bombs they've used on my own? Until they use the entire package, or will google track parts of a package being used?

Comment: For *Consumable items* you don't need to track how many bombs they've been used, because the user can purshase those items/pkg as he want. But for *Non-consumable Items*, they can only be purchased once, and they will be permanently associated to the user's Google account (e.g premium upgrade, a level pack...)

Answer (score 0):

Managed products can onle be purchased once and can not be purchased again until they are consumed. You would need to sell a package of bombs and then consume the product after the last bomb is used.

You have to keep track of number of bombs used. To have it work across devices or if reinstalled you can use Google Saved Game Services.

https://developers.google.com/games/services/common/concepts/savedgames